# Tinymce initizlising textarea with <> tags

Tags: tinymce, textarea, web

Tinymce editor is not rendering editor properly when the content is something like

```
<textarea><p>&lt;sample data&gt;</p></textarea>
```

i.e. `<sample data>`.

When I initialize a TinyMCE editor here, I dont see anything as it looks like it assumes `<sample data>` is an HTML tag.

Please assume I have tinymce.js loaded and I initilize using tinymce.init.

Is there a fix for this? Please let me know if it is a server side fix, or is there a tinymce.init option I could give to fix this problem.

PS: It does look like this is an HTML Entity encoding related issue but I am hardly an expert in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the tinymce config parameter [entity_encoding](http://entity_encoding).

If this does not work you may use this workaround

```
// save content
var saved_content = document.getElementById('id_of_my_textarea').innerHTML;

// init the editor
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'id_of_my_textarea');

// after tinymce is fully initialized do
// you should use the tinymce configuration parameter "setup" rather than this code here
tinymce.get('id_of_my_textarea').setContent(saved_content);
```

Comment: What do you mean by configuration parameter called setup ? Do you mean like  setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onClick.add(function(ed, evt) {
          ed.selection.select(evt.target);                             
      }); ?

Comment: If that is the case , what do I mention in setup ? Thanks for sharing your thoughts .

Comment: you could use ed.onInit... inside the setup function and set the editor content there